# Computing mean of all rasters in a directory using python

Tags: python, raster

I don't have ArcGIS (ArcPy) so I am hoping to use some other python package such as numpy to compute the mean of a list of rasters in a directory (i.e. Raster1.tif + Raster2.tif + Raster3.tif / 3).

I like to input the directory in the console for computations- using this:

```
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

rasters []
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    if i.endswith(".tif"):
```

After this I am not really sure what package or code to use. The only examples I have found online are using ArcPy.

Can anyone help me out?

I am hoping to export a single averaged raster as a 16-bit tif.

Comment: Are the rasters single band images or multi-band?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `rasterio` to read your data as numpy arrays (and write from numpy arrays) and `numpy` to perform the averaging.

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import os

data_dir = '/path/to/data' # Or sys.argv[1]
file_list = glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.tif'))

def read_file(file):
    with rasterio.open(file) as src:
        return(src.read(1))

# Read all data as a list of numpy arrays 
array_list = [read_file(x) for x in file_list]
# Perform averaging
array_out = np.mean(array_list, axis=0)

# Get metadata from one of the input files
with rasterio.open(file_list[0]) as src:
    meta = src.meta

meta.update(dtype=rasterio.float32)

# Write output file
with rasterio.open('/path/to/output/file.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    dst.write(array_out.astype(rasterio.float32), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Loic- this code is now very close to working. Not sure if you know what the source of my traceback error is... I used your code (small typo on line 21 fixed ('scr.meta'). data_dir was assigned sys.argv[1] and put into the output directory. here is my error

Comment: C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\envs\alenv\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py:282: NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform set. Default transform will be applied (Affine.identity())
  s.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_processing/flatfield_compute.py", line 26, in <module>
    with rasterio.open(data_dir, 'w', **meta) as dst:
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\envs\alexenv\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 282, in open
    s.start()
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 986, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.start (rasterio/_io.c:17228)

Comment: Thanks for the typo. Is that really an error you're getting or 'just' a warning? It looks like your input files aren't geo-referenced.

Comment: Hey Loic- yes. My files aren't georeferenced because I am computing flatfields with this script. So my data do not need spatial info. I had tried hashtagging out the metadata part of the script but it still doesn't seem to run. I'll keep playing around with it unless you have some suggestions.

Comment: I just tried with simple pictures taken with my phone (not georeferenced), and the process completes without any problem. Are you sure what you are getting is an error and not a warning? Do all your image have the same exact dimensions?

Answer (score 4):

To compute the mean of a list of rasters in a directory (i.e. Raster1.tif + Raster2.tif + Raster3.tif / 3), it could be used only a part of Loïc Dutrieux rasterio code. For example, in my '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data' directory, next code:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import os

data_dir = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data' # Or sys.argv[1]
file_list = glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.tif'))
raster = [ os.path.split(item)[1] for item in file_list ]

def read_file(file):
    with rasterio.open(file) as src:
        return(src.read(1))

# Read all data as a list of numpy arrays 
array_list = [read_file(x) for x in file_list]
# Perform averaging
for i, array in enumerate(array_list):
    print raster[i], ", mean: ", np.mean(array)
```

produces at the Python Console of QGIS the following result:

```
utah_lake.tif , mean:  116.720311851
b4.ND.tif , mean:  68.2443939062
LT50380322011235PAC01_B6.tif , mean:  162.756999634
b3.ND.tif , mean:  42.4123148545
tiznados_canoa_part_reproj.tif , mean:  610.861699623
LT50380322011235PAC01_B3.tif , mean:  43.0117399461
tiznados_canoa_part.tif , mean:  633.044776
natural_earth.tif , mean:  152.838815689
LT50380322011235PAC01_B4.tif , mean:  68.3190660858
tiznados_canoa.tif , mean:  256.409105513
utah_demUTM2.tif , mean:  1824.71800614
```

If you have issues to install rasterio in your system, you probably will need GDAL. Next code produces the same result as above code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import os

data_dir = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data' # Or sys.argv[1]
file_list = glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.tif'))
raster = [ os.path.split(item)[1] for item in file_list ]

for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
    dataset = gdal.Open(file)
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray()

    print raster[i], ", mean: ", np.mean(data)
```

Comment: thanks xunilk! This code also works! I prefer to output my file as a tiff rather than printing the mean values. However, this code will also be very useful to me for verifying the means before averaging. Thanks so much \